# How upgrade mysql minor version in aurora serverless v1

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I have Aurora Serverless 2.08.3 with mysql 5.7.12 and I would like to upgrade to higher version, eg. 5.7.40.
But command doesn't show 5.7.12 version: -

```
aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier: "Engine": "aurora-mysql", "EngineVersion": "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.08.3",
```

I would like to upgrade EngineVersion

```
aws rds modify-db-cluster \ --db-cluster-identifier prod-franchise-droptica-org \ --engine-version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.11.3 --apply-immediately
```

but you are getting error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the ModifyDBCluster operation: Cannot find upgrade target from 5.7.serverless_mysql_aurora.2.08.3 with requested version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.11.3 for serverless engine mode.
```

So, how to upgrade 5.7.12 to higher minor version in serverless v1?

You also mentioned that you know that there is EOL declared for MySQL 5.7.